# i want to execute a .ps1 powershell script in red hat linux server

Tags: database, linux, powershell

i am having a .ps1 powershell script which executes in window, but my whole data is in linux server, is there any possible way via which i can execute the powershell script in red hat server

the powershell script is :

```
Clear-Host
$path="D:\Deep Backup 26-04-2013\New folder"
$systemname=Read-Host 'Enter System Name'



$files=Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Force -Include *_Registrar.zip*,*.reg.zip*


$counter=1

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $name=$file.name
    [void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.5.4\Assemblies\v2.0\MySql.Data.dll")
    $dbconnect=New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    $dbconnect.ConnectionString="server=localhost;userid=root;password=nPr123*;database=test3;"
    $dbconnect.Open()

    $sql="insert into eid values('"+$name + "','"+$systemname+"')"


    $command=new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sql,$dbconnect)
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()


}
 $sql="insert into eid_unique
       select distinct Packet_name, System_name from eid a
       where not exists (select 1 from eid_unique b
       where a.Packet_name=b.Packet_name);"


    $command=new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sql,$dbconnect)
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$dbconnect.close()
```

Comment: You'd be better off implementing this in bash/ruby/python/perl.

Comment: even with "Pash" as mentioned in the answer there is no way that you will be able to load .NET dll (in you example it is MySql.Data.dll)...as Andy Arismendi mentioned you need to reimplement the script to other scripting language

Comment: I second the recommendation of sticking with the "native" languages of the platform.

Comment: @Tomas - There is a Mono MySQL binding (or I would not have bothered to mention this as an option) http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL

Answer (score 11):

Four years later from original question microsoft releases powershell for linux. And it's opensource: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

In linux environment you can use syntax like this: (script.ps1, executable)

```
#!/usr/bin/powershell -Command

write-host -fore Green "executing PowerShell!";
```

Answer (score 5):

[Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash) is a cross-platform mono clone of Powershell which is under active development. 
You only need to download, build it with `xbuild`, and run it.
Just like with Powershell on Windows you can execute your script with

```
& '/path/to/script.ps1'
```

Comment: "This repository has been archived by the owner on Feb 4, 2019. It is now read-only."

Answer (score 3):

After [installing](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006397/45156) powershell, easy enough:

```
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ ./hello_world.ps1
hello world
done
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ cat hello_world.ps1 
#!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command


echo "hello world"
"done"


thufir@dur:~/powershell$
```

Not sure why it's `pwsh` and not `powershell`, but that's Linux for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily install on linux with

```
snap install powershell --classic
```

> This revision of snap "powershell" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at risk.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Pash](http://pash.sourceforge.net/) may work for you.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't look like it's being actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a straightforward approach that helped me. Please follow the official Microsoft documentation for this. There are two steps to this question.

- Installing PowerShell (on your OS)
- Running the PowerShell script

**Installing PowerShell:**

Following URLs will assist you to install PowerShell in your machine.

- Windows: [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2)
- Linux OSs: [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2)
- MacOS: [URL - for direct download option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.2#installation-via-direct-download) (I used this option)

To confirm your installation, open up a terminal and run `pwsh` (this is for mac). You will see the following:

[image]

**Running the PowerShell script:**

Next, in the PowerShell terminal, run the following command. Replace `my-script.ps1`, with your script name:

```
./my-script.ps
```