# How to Invoke "Powershell script file" from Java in Linux operating system

Tags: java, linux, powershell

Class:-

=====================

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestPowershell {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException     
    {    
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process proc = runtime.exec("cmd powershell \"\\Test\\Powershell\\powershell.ps1\" ");

    proc.getOutputStream().close();

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        reader.close();

        proc.getOutputStream().close();

    }

}
```

I am trying to execute a powershell file by using java in linux environment , i am getting exceptions (above i attached class and exceptions), kindly provide me a test class which can execute powershell script file in linux. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying to execute a powershell file by using java in linux environment , i am getting exceptions (above i attached class and exceptions), kindly provide me a test class which can execute powershell script file in linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to add that as a preface to your question :)

Comment: I tried your example too, but this only showing same thing, 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Wait, I just noticed the "in linux environment" part ; I wouldn't expect your OS to have a powershell implementation installed. Would typing `powershell` in your linux shell do anything? I expect it'd just raise the `command not found` you're getting now. Same with `cmd`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759523/i-want-to-execute-a-ps1-powershell-script-in-red-hat-linux-server) provides way to execute powershell scripts under a linux environment, this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes @Aaron, i have one more doubt , did your code work "Host" as local in Windows os ? and did your code work in "AWS" environment ? Guide me if have any idea !!!

Comment: Not sure what code you're referring to, the answer below isn't mine. What is the powershell code supposed to do? Depending on the answer you could 1) transcribe it into Java (would be portable, might not be possible if its action are related to the OS), 2) write a bash (or other linux shell) equivalent to your powershell script (can do OS stuff on both OSes, but needs twice the amount of work & maintenance) or 3) use a way to execute your powershell script under linux

Comment: @kishorek Please edit the question and include your comments in the question body.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta is ok now ???

Comment: Your code would be much easier for other people to examine and analyze, if you did not put a blank line between every single statement.  Blank lines should separate methods, and major blocks of functionality within methods.

Answer (score 0):

1st download the FreeSSHD http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download in your windows(server). make sure run it as Administrator.

for setup FreeSSHD follow this URL http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/ after setup you can ssh that windows system from linux or using putty.

to execute powershell script from linux to remote windows system using java

```
package com.sysvana.router.config;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;
public class Test {
static String hostname = "10.1.10.60";
static String username = "administrator";
static String password = "P@ssw0rd"; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
conn.connect();
boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword (username, password);
if (isAuthenticated == false){
System.out.println("authentication failed");
} 
System.out.println(isAuthenticated);
Session sess = conn.openSession (); 
sess.execCommand ("powershell C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.ps1"); 
InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler (sess.getStdout ()); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
while (true)
{
String line = br.readLine ();
if (line == null) break;
System.out.println (line);
}
System.out.println ("Exit code" + sess.getExitStatus ());
sess.close ();
conn.close ();
}
}
```

use Ganymed SSH-2 jar http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/

Comment: This is useful to execute powershell script on remote machines, but is a bit overkill to solve OP's problem (he only needs to execute local PS scripts AFAICT)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not actually trying to run PowerShell. You're using this:

```
runtime.exec("cmd powershell \"\\Test\\Powershell\\powershell.ps1\" ")
```

which means it's trying to run a file called `cmd`, which is not part of Linux.

Also, in another part of the code, you're trying to run `powershell.exe`. Typically, Linux programs don't have a `.exe` extension. You may have ported your Java application from Windows, but you need to be aware that Linux is different. It doesn't come with Powershell as standard, and doesn't use .exe file extension.

You can install PowerShell at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell.

On Linux, PowerShell (once installed from the above) is invoked with the `pwsh` command. You will need to change your Java program accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

Finally, I got to know while working with PowerShell we should run the script in windows OS only because Microsoft is the owner for PowerShell and they give more features in Windows OS.

what I did is, I ran the script in Windows OS & generated a CSV file and kept in SFTP folder, by using java I loaded my file and processed my next process.